# SWIFT / iOS: Data takes a few seconds to load when screen appears

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I've created a user profile screen, and when loaded, the data takes a few seconds to appear. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Here's the view controller in the storyboard:

[image]

As you can see, there is placeholder text.  The issue is that this text appears very briefly when this screen is loaded (before the data is retrieved from the database).

Here is what the screen looks like when the data is fully loaded:

[image]

I've seen that an Activity Indicator on the previous screen may be a good solution. Can anyone verify this and point me to a good SWIFT tutorial or Stack Overflow solution?

**UPDATE:** 
I'm loading the data on the previous View Controller as suggested.  The issue that I'm running into is that the constants which I store my data are not accessible in prepareForSegue -

```
override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {


            let query = PFQuery(className:"UserProfileData")
            query.whereKey("username", equalTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)

            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    if let objects = objects! as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {

                            let yourselfObject = object["yourself"] as! String?
                            let brideGroomObject = object["brideGroom"] as! String?

                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            }


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "RSVPToUserProfile" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? UserProfileViewController {

            destination.yourselfPassed = yourselfObject
            destination.brideGroomPassed = brideGroomObject

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Show your code. How do you download and how do you update the UI

Comment: I've added the User Profile View Controller code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33291125/2303865

Comment: if you still need help please let me know

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added: "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in <UI Updates> })" around the UI updates and it doesn't fix the issue.  Any other suggestions? What about an Activity Indicator on the previous screen?

Comment: edit/update your question with the dispatch_async code that you have just added

Comment: try moving your code from willappear to didappear

Comment: Code has been updated, thanks.  I also tried putting the code in DidAppear and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: How long is this delay? You are downloading it from the internet, so a couple of seconds it is normal.

Comment: The delay is 1-2 seconds.  I've just never seen an app do this, so there must be a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is actually very simple... Just remove the placeholder text from the storyboard. That way it won't "appear very briefly."

If you don't like the idea of a blank screen, then move the loading code to the place where the view is being presented. Don't present the view until after the loading code is complete. You will have to pass the data to the view controller at presentation time if you do this.

-- EDIT --

*Do not override `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`!* Doing so will not accomplish your goal.

I say again. Move the loading code to the place where you are *calling* perform segue, and delay the call until after your data is loaded. (I.E. move the perform segue call into the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` block after you get the items.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I did what you suggested, and yes, the screen is blank for a few seconds.  Do you know what class I would need to add the data retrieval code in order for the data to be loaded at presentation time?  Thanks!

Comment: You would need to add it to the view controller that presents this one, and move the presentation logic so it doesn't trigger until *after* the data is loaded.

Comment: I see... So could a potential solution be to load the data in prepareForSegue in the previous view controller?

Comment: No, by then it's too late. You have to put the load data code in place of triggering the segue, and then trigger the segue after the data has been loaded. Don't forget to pass the data to the new view controller in prepare for segue though.

Comment: I loaded the data in prepareForSegue on the previous View Controller, and then loaded the data in viewDidAppear on the User Profile View Controller.  It's a bit faster, but still takes 1-1.5 seconds to load.  Do you know of any way to make the user experience a bit better?  Even if there's an activity indicator which appears while the passed data is loaded.  I understand that this is such a small issue, but I'm very particular with user experience, and I'm adamant on getting this fixed.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Like I said, load the data at the point the segue is *triggered* not in `prepareForSegue`. Then transfer the already loaded data to the new view controller in the `prepareForSegue`. So, for example, find the place where you are doing the `performSegue`, *replace* the code there with the load data code, and then do the performSegue *after* the data is done loading. Either way, the user sees an activity indicator your just moving it to a different place. Since you are big on smooth UI, you will like this http://bit.ly/1N4ziA2

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I am now loading the data in the performSegueWithIdentifier function in the first view controller.  However, I cannot seem to access the data in prepareForSegue.  The error it gives me is 'use of unresolved identifier'.  I've updated my code in the original post.  I feel like I'm almost there.